# What does "each user must type in their password before they will be able to unlock the disk" mean?

Tags: password, filevault, unlock, macos

I am setting up File Vault 2 on my Macbook Pro under Yosemite and I see the following message,

> each user must type in their password before they will be able to
>   unlock the disk

[image: Example]

I don't actually have the password for the other account on the computer to verify the behavior to expect from the Admin account.

What exactly will this user see when they login? Will they be able to use the computer or will I have to unlock the disk for them and reconfigure FileVault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially all users not enabled won' t be capable of unlocking the disk.

1. If you hit Continue, your Mac will be restarted
2. All users not enabled previously will not appear at the first login screen and thus won't be able to unlock the disk.

   Once the disk is unlocked, all users may be used though. Even the  previously not 'enabled' users are available by 'user switching' or a 'second' login screen.
3. After logging in with an enabled user your system will be encrypted.

   [image: encryption]
4. You may enable users subsequently by clicking the lock and 'Enable User...'

   [image]
5. Enter the user's password and click OK, then Done

   [image]
6. All users enabled subsequently will reappear at the first login screen, may unlock the disk and log in as usual.

Comment: Thanks. I should add that without enabling the user I don't see the 'Admin' user on the login screen as you mentioned, but they appear once my user has logged in.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon Where do they reappear?

Comment: In the user switcher and the post-startup login screen. Essentially the first login screen unlocks the hard drive, but once unlocked the login screen shows all users.

Comment: @JamesMcMahon OK i will add that. I just tested encryption password=main admin password...

Answer (score 0):

FileVault encrypts the hard drive -- these users are able to decrypt the drive, though standard unix access controls will prevent non-admins from looking at other user home directories.  I suspect that any user with the ability to unlock the drive and physical access to the machine could boot into single user mode and see the hard drive.